# Optimistic concurrency on multi-table complex entity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers, optimistic-locking

I have a complex entity (let's call it `Thing`) which is represented in SQL Server as many tables: one parent table `dbo.Thing` with several child tables `dbo.ThingBodyPart`, `dbo.ThingThought`, etc.  We've implemented optimistic concurrency using a single `rowversion` column on `dbo.Thing`, using the [`UPDATE OUTPUT INTO` technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359050/getting-latest-rowversion-timestamp-value-in-update-statement-sql-server).  This has been working great, until we added a trigger to `dbo.Thing`.  I'm looking for advice in choosing a different approach, because I'm fairly convinced that my current approach cannot be fixed.

Here is our current code:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateThing
    @id uniqueidentifier,
    -- ...
    -- ... other parameters describing what to update...
    -- ...
    @rowVersion binary(8) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY

    -- ...
    -- ... update lots of Thing's child rows...
    -- ...

    DECLARE @t TABLE (
        [RowVersion] binary(8) NOT NULL
    );

    UPDATE dbo.Thing
    SET ModifiedUtc = sysutcdatetime()
    OUTPUT INSERTED.[RowVersion] INTO @t
    WHERE
        Id = @id
        AND [RowVersion] = @rowVersion;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RAISERROR('Thing has been updated by another user.', 16, 1);

    COMMIT;

    SELECT @rowVersion = [RowVersion] FROM @t;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    EXEC usp_Rethrow_Error;
END CATCH
```

This worked absolutely beautifully, until we added an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger to `dbo.Thing`.  Now the stored procedure no longer returns the new `@rowVersion` value, but returns the old unmodified value.  I'm at a loss.  Are there other ways to approach optimistic concurrency that would be as effective and easy as the one above, but would also work with triggers?

---

To illustrate what exactly goes wrong with this code, consider this test code:

```sql
DECLARE
    @id uniqueidentifier = 'b0442c71-dbcb-4e0c-a178-1a01b9efaf0f',
    @oldRowVersion binary(8),
    @newRowVersion binary(8),
    @expected binary(8);

SELECT @oldRowVersion = [RowVersion]
FROM dbo.Thing
WHERE Id = @id;

PRINT '@oldRowVersion = ' + convert(char(18), @oldRowVersion, 1);

DECLARE @t TABLE (
    [RowVersion] binary(8) NOT NULL
);

UPDATE dbo.Thing
SET ModifiedUtc = sysutcdatetime()
OUTPUT INSERTED.[RowVersion] INTO @t
WHERE
    Id = @id
    AND [RowVersion] = @oldRowVersion;

PRINT '@@ROWCOUNT = ' + convert(varchar(10), @@ROWCOUNT);

SELECT @newRowVersion = [RowVersion] FROM @t;

PRINT '@newRowVersion = ' + convert(char(18), @newRowVersion, 1);

SELECT @expected = [RowVersion]
FROM dbo.Thing
WHERE Id = @id;

PRINT '@expected = ' + convert(char(18), @expected, 1);

IF @newRowVersion = @expected PRINT 'Pass!'
ELSE PRINT 'Fail.  :('
```

When the trigger is not present, this code correctly outputs:

```
@oldRowVersion = 0x0000000000016CDC

(1 row(s) affected)
@@ROWCOUNT = 1
@newRowVersion = 0x000000000004E9D1
@expected = 0x000000000004E9D1
Pass!
```

When the trigger is present, we do not receive the expected value:

```
@oldRowVersion = 0x0000000000016CDC

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
@@ROWCOUNT = 1
@newRowVersion = 0x0000000000016CDC
@expected = 0x000000000004E9D1
Fail.  :(
```

---

Any ideas for a different approach?

I was assuming that an `UPDATE` was an atomic operation, which it is, except when there are triggers, when apparently it's not.  Am I wrong?  This seems really bad, in my opinion, with potential concurrency bugs lurking behind every statement.  If the trigger *really is* `INSTEAD OF`, shouldn't I get back the correct timestamp, as though the trigger's `UPDATE` was the one I actually executed?  Is this a SQL Server bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my esteemed co-workers, [Jonathan MacCollum](http://blogs.technet.com/b/themasterblog/archive/2013/06/19/introducing-our-latest-sql-server-2008-microsoft-certified-master-jonathan-w-maccollum.aspx), pointed me to this [bit of documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

> #### INSERTED
>
> Is a column prefix that specifies the value added by the insert or update operation.
> Columns prefixed with INSERTED reflect the value after the UPDATE, INSERT, or MERGE statement is completed but *before triggers are executed*.

From this, I presume that I need to modify my stored procedure, splitting the one `UPDATE` into an `UPDATE` followed by a `SELECT [RowVersion] ...`.

```
UPDATE dbo.Thing
SET ModifiedUtc = sysutcdatetime()
WHERE
    Id = @id
    AND [RowVersion] = @rowVersion;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RAISERROR('Thing has been updated by another user.', 16, 1);

COMMIT;

SELECT @rowVersion = [RowVersion]
FROM dbo.Thing
WHERE Id = @id;
```

I think I can still rest assured that my stored procedure is not accidentally overwriting anybody else's changes, but I should no longer assume that the data that the caller of the stored procedure holds is still up-to-date.  There's a chance that the new `@rowVersion` value returned by the stored procedure is actually the result of someone else's update, not mine.  So actually, there's no point in returning the `@rowVersion` at all.  After executing this stored procedure, the caller should re-fetch the `Thing` and all of its child records in order to be sure its picture of the data is consistent.

... which further leads me to conclude that `rowversion` columns are not the best choice for implementing optimistic locking, which sadly is their sole purpose.  I would be much better off using a manually incremented `int` column, with a query like:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.Thing
SET Version = @version + 1
WHERE
    Id = @id
    AND Version = @version;
```

The `Version` column is checked *and* incremented in a single atomic operation, so there's no chance for other statements to slip in-between.  I don't have to *ask* the database what the new value is, because I *told* it what the new value is.  As long as the `Version` column contains the value I'm expecting (and assuming all other people updating this row are also playing by the rules - correctly incrementing `Version`), I can know that the `Thing` is still exactly as I left it.  At least, I think...